# HTML Body Size Issues

Tags: html, css

I thought that if I set my overall

```
HTML, Body{
    height:200%;
}
```

I could have a screen that scrolls down rather than having my individual elements scroll down. Now I want to make my screen fit my elements, but not get too large.

i.e. to be as big as it needs to and allow my WHOLE WEBPAGE to scroll to accommodate that but at the same time not be larger than necessary.

I tried to use margin:-50% on my html, body code area, but it did not work.

My site is on codeacademy.com:

codeacademy.com/dungrove34/codebits/YbNODd

Comment: post all your css and html or just make a jsfiddle and post here.

Comment: I added a link to the code.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you want

Answer (score 0):

try this one 
**html**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
     <p>inside this tag u can add your elements.</p>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px; 
}
.container{
  width:980px;
  height:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
 }
```

this div with class container help u to make something like frame,after u add your elements to `<div class="container"></div>` ,height of this div become fix with elements height.

**look at this** and try to add element with height. 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUY4t/3/)